# There Is No Media Output In A Specific Folder After Finishing My Render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

As an absolute beginner I am just figuring things out. I was working on a project, which I rendered, but there is no output file in my output folder.

The Render Scene And Options:

[image: The Render Scene And Options.]

My Project In Rendered View:

[image: My Project In Rendered View.]

Comment: Please read the [workflow](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/output/render_panel.html#render-panel) section, it clearly states, you have to save your image. [render an image](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/output/render_panel.html#render-panel) F12, it will be shown in the Image Editor. Save the image from the [image editor](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/uv_image/image/introduction.html#image-menu) Alt S.

Answer (score 1):

In blender, animation renders/videos are automatically saved in the output folder location. But image renders are not. This is probably because, many a time we test render a scene to see how things are shaping up and we don't want to clutter our output folder.

In-order to save a rendered image manually, after the rendering is done, go to image editor.You can do this by clicking on bottom right dropdown of any window and clicking UV/Image editor as shown.[image] 
Once you are in this window, you can click on image menu and click 'save as image'as shown. [image]
Alternatively, you can just press F3 key without even accessing the image editor window. Doing any of these, will direct you to a screen that asks you to select the folder location to save.

If you want the image to be saved automatically, you can use the following addon. https://github.com/elfnor/blender_auto_save_on_render

Please note that I didn't write this add-on. I only came across this while searching.